# Connection timed out Issue When hits API Magento 2.4.2

Tags: mysql, azure, magento2, magento2.4

Magento showing the below error when it hits the apis, because of this its increase the api response time. Due to that, site becomes slow and sometime site is not loading properly.

```
[2023-01-30 18:17:12] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out {"report_id":"dc6edaaa89a6f61277cd3a09f088d68d1
9d8d50d1e471213a6e0f389867caa0b","exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection
timed out at /mnt/mageprod/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144, PDOException(code: 2002)
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out at /mnt/mageprod/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstrac
t.php:128)"} []
```

How can I fix this issue?

We just hit the APIs and checked the response time and it is working fine.

Apart from that we are not getting any Magento or MySQL issues in log file.

We have integrated azure with MySQL.

Comment: Can you connect with mysql client from the place where the application is running? I timeout happens when a connection cannot be established.

Comment: We can connect mysql properly with application. Site is also running properly.

Comment: So, this errors happens from time to time? Do you close your connections? This can be some old open connection inside some kind of pool.

Comment: Yes This error started  showing in logs from afternoon. In morning not getting any errors.
We can close connection but site will down as it's already on PROD

Comment: I asked if you are closing your connections in your code, but this can also be an overload in MySQL. Take a look in MySQL logs.

Comment: No We are not closing the connection in code